# SSH session show à instead of @

Tags: 16.04, locale, sshd

I have Ubuntu VM (installed on esxi). I was trying to run a curl command over a ssh session:

```
curl -L https:// xyz.com/latest
```

After running above command my ssh session started showing as below:

```
panlabàpanlab:¨$
```

It was showing as below before:

```
panlab@panlab:~$
```

When I login to console of my VM it shows properly but on SSH I get above kind of character. If I want to type @ I could not type it.

How do I correct it?

I have tried to run below command also but it didn't help:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Comment: Maybe you export the locale settings to the VM. What does the `locale` command output when you are connected to it via SSH?